write adapter-specific runsettings
In the docs for the .runsettings-file there's a section for adapter-specific settings:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Use 0 for maximum process-level parallelization. This does not force parallelization within the test DLL (on the thread-level). You can also change it from the Test menu; choose "Run tests in parallel". Unchecked = 1 (only 1), checked = 0 (max). -->
    <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
    <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
  </RunConfiguration>

  <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->

  <MyAdapter>
    <WorkSpacePath>myfile.txt</WorkSpacePath>
  </MyAdapter>

</RunSettings>

I've written my adapter by implementing ITestDiscoverer and ITestExecutor. Now I want to configure my adapter using the settings-file, but there's no documentation about how to do that. While debugging my adapter I noticed that the IRunContext-interface provides a property for the RunSettings, that also includes my section.
Of course I could just parse the entire file, but that seems odd as that file already is de-serialized into said property. So I wonder how I can read these adapter-specific sections. I've tried using context.RunSettings.GetSettings("MyAdapter"), but that gave me an ObjectMode.SettingsException:

Settings Provider named 'MyAdapter' was not found.  The settings can not be loaded.

